# Java - Using Hashtable with Interface as value

Tags: java, generics, interface, hashtable

I have one interface IMyInterface. A set of classes that implements this interface : Class1, Class2...

Now i want to create a Hashtable that stores any class implementing IMyInterface.

```
Hashtable<String,? extends IMyInterface> ht = new Hashtable<String,? extends IMyInterface>();
ht.add("foo",new Class1());
```

The compiler complains that it cannot instiate ht and that it cannot add Class1 because
the add method is not defined to do so. add method expects IMyInterface :\

How can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
Hashtable<String, IMyInterface> table = new Hashtable<String, IMyInterface>();
table.put("foo", new Class1());
```

Given that `Class1` implements `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Thanks for reply ;) I had to use put instead of add !

Answer (score 0):

The type you have written, `Hashtable<String,? extends IMyInterface>` means *a Hashtable which stores as values elements of some subtype of `IMyInterface`, but we don't know which one*. This is acceptable for a variable type (and then you can't add any keys to it, since the compiler can't be sure you are using the right subtype), but it is not usable for a constructor invocation.

What you want is a `Hashtable<String, IMyInterface>`, which means *any object implementing IMyInterface* can be a value.

By the way, better use `Map<String, IMyInterface>` for the variable and `HashMap<String, IMyInterface>` for the constructor instead of `Hashtable`.

Comment: why hashmap is better than hashtable ? i need concurrent access on the hashtable.

Comment: I disagree with using `Map`. This line of code is obviously implementation detail, not a public API. There's no need for encapsulation and abstraction, this is not a blackbox. Don't use interface here, use exact type.

Comment: About HashMap versus Hashtable: Often it would be better to use external synchronization, since you are anyways accessing other variables than the hash-table, where the build-in synchronization does not help. Additionally, Hashtable has old method names additionally to the newer map ones, which causes confusion. But do what you want, it is not really important here - in the worst case you do some superfluous synchronization.

Comment: About Map versus Hashxxx (@irreputable): I would always recommend using the interface as variable type when no specific features of the exact implementation class are needed. The exact type is longer to write (and read), and gives no additional benefit here, as it is not needed after initialization. And in the case of Hashtable, this class has several public methods not in the Map interface (but duplicated by other methods), which can be used when declared as Hashtable, which complicates later switching of the implementation. (**For write-only-code, it does not matter.**)

Comment: Everybody would recommend that, but it's wrong. Usually it's not arbitrary what Map impl is chosen. If I need a concurrent map, declaring it simply as `Map` would be very misleading. The argument about switching implementation easily is only valid in rare cases. Generally it's never easy, you have to examine all the usages anyway. Nobody can read a `Map` variable declaration line alone and say, ok, I can substitute it with any `Map` implementation. However if we are more specific, say declaring it as `Hashtable`, then it is actually easier to see it can be replaced with a `ConcurrentHashMap`.